# git using authorized_keys as authentication

Tags: git, authentication, server

I followed [the official tutorial](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) in order to setup a git server for the first time. When I executed the following:

```
$ git remote add origin git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
$ git push origin master
```

I was asked for the password of `git@gitserver`, which I thought was weird, but entered it anyway.

Then when I tried to clone the repository by doing this:

```
$ git clone git@gitserver:/opt/git/project.git
```

or push to it using this:

```
$ git push origin master
```

I was asked for the password for `git@gitserver` every time. I checked and `authorized_users` contains the public key of the user that's trying to push or clone. Also, I tried what is suggested answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/232373/how-to-tell-git-which-private-key-to-use), but that didn't help.

How can I set the server and the client so that I am not asked for a password every time I commit?

#### UPDATE

Output of `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@gitserver`:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitserver [XXX_REDACTED_gitserver_IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA XXX_REDACTED_PUBLIC_KEY_XXX
debug1: Host 'gitserver' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/XXX/.ssh/known_hosts:12
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
git@gitserver's password:
```

Comment: So by that suggested answer, I presume you've set up your `.ssh/config`, but what happens when you run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@gitserver` (or -i to wherever your private key is)?

Comment: It still asks for the password of the git user.

Comment: And yes, I've setup .ssh/config as so: host & HostName are <ip address of server>; IdentityFile is ~/.ssh/id_rsa; User is git.

Comment: It would likely help if you chould attach the output of `ssh -v -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa git@gitserver`

Comment: Oh, thanks, updating the question...

Comment: Okay, this is embarrassing... I had the wrong public key in the `authorized_keys` file. Thanks for the help, @Bujiraso, if you add your comment as an answer I will accept it (i.e. using ssh -i and ssh -v -i to debug the problem).

Comment: no worries -- it happens to everyone. I added an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure you're using the correct private/public key pair. 
You can verify this by directly pointing to the key using `ssh -v -i [private key file] git@gitserver` and checking the output.